# Read ini files without section names

Tags: perl, ini, gnu-coreutils

I want to make a configuration file which hold some objects, like this (where of course none of the paramaters can be considered as a primary key)

```
param1=abc
param2=ghj

param1=bcd
param2=hjk
; always the sames parameters
```

This file could be read, lets say with [`Config::IniFiles`](https://metacpan.org/module/Config::IniFiles), because it has a direct transcription into ini file, like this

```
[0]
param1=abc
param2=ghj

[1]
param1=bcd
param2=hjk
```

with, for example, something like

```
perl -pe 'if (m/^\s*$/ || !$section ) print "[", ($section++ || 0) , "]"'
```

And finish with

```
open my $fh, '<', "/path/to/config_file.ini" or die $!;
$cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => $fh );
(...parse here the sections starting with 0.)
```

But, I here ask me some question about the thing becoming quite complex....

(A) Is There a way to transform the $fh, so that it is not required to execute the perl one-liner BEFORE reading the file sequentially? So, to transform the file during perl is actually reading it.

or

(B) Is there a module to read my wonderfull flat database?  Or something approching?  I let myslef said, that Gnu coreutils does this kind of flat file reading, but I cannot remember how.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use a simple configuration file with severall objects in it.  I have, of course, more verbose solution like xml, json, ...

Comment: @MUYBelgium: Is there a reason why you can't start with a more standard ini file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple subclass of [Config::INI::Reader](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::INI::Reader):

```
package MyReader;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Config::INI::Reader';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new( @_ );

    $self->{section} = 0;

    return $self;
}


sub starting_section { 0 };

sub can_ignore { 0 };

sub parse_section_header {
     my ( $self, $line ) = @_;

    return $line =~ /^\s*$/ ? ++$self->{section} : undef ;
}

1;
```

With your input this gives:

```
% perl -MMyReader -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper( MyReader->read_file("cfg") )'
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   'param2' => 'hjk',
                   'param1' => 'bcd'
                 },
          '0' => {
                   'param2' => 'ghj',
                   'param1' => 'abc'
                 }
        };
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem as stated, it is a huge amount of code to do something very simple. And it is far from obvious that all it does is emulate an ordinary `.ini` file with missing section headers. I believe the proper answer lies elsewhere, but it depends on the origin of the strange file format which the OP hasn't explained.

Comment: Yeah, it's overkill, but it does address the OP's immediate needs. Sometimes you need to work with the information you've got.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable reference instead of a file name to create a filehandle that reads from it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $config = "/path/to/config_file.ini";

my $content = do {
  local $/;
  open my $fh, "<", $config;
  "\n". <$fh>;
};

# one liner replacement
my $section = 0;
$content =~ s/^\s*$/ "\n[". $section++ ."]" /mge;

open my $fh, '<', \$content;
my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => $fh );
# ...
```

Comment: If the object Config::IniFile accepted a reference to a scalar, each 'paragraph' of the config file may be parsed separately, making the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the modified data in a real file or a string variable, but I suggest that you use *paragraph mode* by setting the *input record separator* `$/` to the empty string. Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
  local $/ = '';  # Read file in "paragraphs"
  my $section = 0;
  while (<DATA>) {
    printf "[%d]\n", $section++;
    print;
  }
}

__DATA__
param1=abc
param2=ghj

param1=bcd
param2=hjk
```

**output**

```
[0]
param1=abc
param2=ghj

[1]
param1=bcd
param2=hjk
```

---

**Update**

If you read the file into a string, adding section identifiers as above, then you can read the result directly into a `Config::IniFiles` object using a string reference, for instance

```
my $config = Config::IniFiles->new(-file => \$modified_contents)
```

This example shows the *tie* interface, which results in a Perl hash that contains the configuration information. I have used `Data::Dump` only to show the structure of the resultant hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::IniFiles;

my $config;
{
  open my $fh, '<', 'config_file.ini' or die "Couldn't open config file: $!";
  my $section = 0;
  local $/ = '';
  while (<$fh>) {
    $config .= sprintf "[%d]\n", $section++;
    $config .= $_;
  }
};

tie my %config, 'Config::IniFiles', -file => \$config;

use Data::Dump;
dd \%config;
```

**output**

```
{
  # tied Config::IniFiles
  "0" => {
           # tied Config::IniFiles::_section
           param1 => "abc",
           param2 => "ghj",
         },
  "1" => {
           # tied Config::IniFiles::_section
           param1 => "bcd",
           param2 => "hjk",
         },
}
```

Comment: @MUYBelgium: I don't understand your comment at all, particularly your use of quotation marks. It is difficult to discern whether you are seeking wisdom, or just hoping for more fuel for your rhetoric. If you look at [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) you will see that each of the short names has a reason and a mnemonic. I hope you can understand that an idiom like `substr($str, $-[0], $+[0]-$-[0])` is preferable to the COBOL-like `substr($str, $LAST_MATCH_START[0], $LAST_MATCH_END[0] - $LAST_MATCH_START[0])`?

Comment: @MUYBelgium: Hmm. It seems that the administrators took a dim view of your attitude as well. Please think carefully about your manner and style when you post here. The vast majority of Stack Overflow's contributors take pride in their posts, and it is inappropriate to wade in with a pompous and dismissive retort.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to perform operations on a flux of objects (as Powershell) instead of a flux of text, so

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use English;

sub operation {
    # do something with objects
    ...
}

{
local $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = '';
# object are separated with empty lines
while (<STDIN>) {
    #                  key       value
    my %object = ( m/^ ([^=]+) = ([[:print:]]*) $ /xmsg ); 
    # key cannot have = included, which is the delimiter
    # value are printable characters (one line only) 
    operation ( \%object )  
}
```

A like also other answers.